# sequence of functions converges almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis

I am doing this question as exercise.

I would appreciate that if you guys are willing to discuss this with me.

Prove that for any measurable function f on [0,1] there exists a sequence $f_{n}$, $n \geq 1 $, of continuous functions on [0,1] such that

f(x)= $\lim_{n \to \infty}f_{n}(x)$ almost everywhere on [0,1].

Comment: Are you assuming boundedness?

Comment: There is no assumption about that@Keaton

Answer (score 0):

Well, every measurable function is the limit of a sequence of simple functions, and continuous functions with compact support are dense in simple functions in the $L^p$-norm.

The proof , for the case where $f$ is bounded that I think is standard is this:

Let $f$ be bounded , so that $-\infty<m\leq f \leq M< \infty$

Now, partition the y-interval $[-m,M]$ into n equal parts --each of height $(M-m)/n$, and consider the simple functions with values {$M,(m-1)(M-m)/m, (m-2)M/m,.....n+M/n$}, i.e., these are the upper-limits of the partition of $[-m, M]$ into equal parts. From the elements of these sets, you create the simple functions with values the elements of this set. You then let $n\rightarrow \infty $ , and you see that these simple functions (seen as a formal sum of characteristic functions ) approximate your f. Now, we approximate characteristic functions with/by continuous functions: A simple function is, graphically, a collection of line segments (from consecutive values in the partition set) that overlap/intersect only at the endpoints. This jump at the endpoints is the only place where the simple function is not continuous, because of a gap. Now, you solve this, by joining the endpoints between consecutive values by a line segment.

If this is O.K, we can consider the case where $f$ takes the value $\infty$. But, I'm sorry, I need to go now, they're closing the library, and I still have no home internet. If this is not O.K, let me know, I'll answer tomorrow--sorry.

Comment: Actually I am taking real analysis now. Would you please prove this by using the materials from real analysis. Thanks though@user99680

Comment: Sure; let me first do a sketch of the case where f is bounded: you partition your range from M=max to m=min, in equal increments of n, then you approximate the function in each subinterval by y max. Then you let n go to $\infty$. For the continuous part, you are trying to approximate the characteristic function $\chi_{E_i}$ , where $E_i$ is the set(interval) where $f$ takes the value $y_i$. This comes down to joining the endpoints of the intervals $E_{y_i}$ with $E_{y_(i-1)}$ by line intervals--so that the resulting function is continuous; to avoid the jumps between the $y_i's$.

Comment: Do you get the idea; can you take it from there, at least to get an idea of the proof?

Comment: I really appreciate that. I got your ideas and I need think about it and we might discuss later@user99680

Comment: Sure; glad it helped.Let me know and we will follow up.